# Comparing every element in a list with the next one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers `a` and I want to iterate through every element of it, and if the element is smaller or the same size as the next element in the list (the upcoming index-neighbour), I want to convert the element into a string and concatenate "000" onto it. But if it's larger than the next element, I want to concatenate "111" onto it.

I use Python 3.7.3.

Here's what I've already tried:

```
a = [41433, 23947, 10128, 89128, 29523, 47106]

for I in a:
      if a[I] <= a[I+1]:
             a[I] = str(a[I] + "000")
      else:
             a[I] = str(a[I] + "111")
```

I've actuallly tried a lot more than that, but nothing worked.
When I run the code, I always get "IndexError: list index out of range".

I'm quite new in Python, anyone know a solution?

Comment: Given your description, all elements but the last one are converted to strings.  Correct? So, `for i in range(len(a)-1): a[i] = str(a[i]) + ('000' if a[i] <= a[i+1] else '111')`

Comment: So what is your expected output, and what is the treatment for the last item in the list where it can't be compared to the one after it?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 4):

Your `I` value isn't an index, it's an element in `a` (41433, 23947 ect), so `a[41433]` doesn't exist.

Try using a range

```
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
  if a[i] <= a[i+1]:
    a[i] = str(a[i]) + "000"
  else:
    a[i] = str(a[i]) + "111"
```

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic way would be to use `enumerate`, which generates tuples of `(index, list[index)`.

```
for idx, val in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    if val <= a[idx+1]:
        a[idx] = str(a[idx]) + "000"
    else:
        a[idx] = str(a[idx]) + "111"
```

**Notes**
Loop until second-to-last item by using `a[:-1]` so that you don't run into index out of bounds errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would use itertools to create two iterators for your list, and zip them together so that you get pairs of successive values:

```
from itertools import tee

i1, i2 = tee(a)
next(i2, None)    # advances i2 by one step
pairs = zip(i1, i2)
a = [str(elem1)+'000' 
        if elem1 <= elem2 else str(elem1)+'111' 
        for elem1, elem2 in pairs]
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate is perfect for this use case. it will also increase readability:

```
a = [41433, 23947, 10128, 89128, 29523, 47106]                  

for index, elem in enumerate(a[:-1]):                           
    if a[index] <= a[index+1]:                                  
        a[index] = str(a[index]) + "000"                     
    else:                                                       
        a[index] = str(a[index]) + "111"                     
print(a)
```

['41433111', '23947111', '10128000', '89128111', '29523000', 47106]